# Computing dot product between vectors in Sympy

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I have been trying to compute the dot product of two vectors in Sympy. Here is my code:

```
from sympy.physics.vector import * 
N = ReferenceFrame('N')
v1 = sqrt(3)*N.x + N.y 
v2 = sqrt(3)*N.x - N.y 
dot(v1, v2)
```

However, I receive an error that "dot" works only when the arguments are vectors.
When I write:

```
type(v1)
```

I am informed that "v1" is a symbol, not a vector. However, "N.x, N.y"  are vectors.

How can I compute this dot product in Sympy?

UPDATE:
I know know that the issue is that I have the expression sqrt(3). So, I guess the question is how to do symbolic dot product calculations?

Answer (score 1):

It works for me.  My imports are a bit different, but that shouldn't make a difference

```
In [1]: run mysympy.py     # isympy setup

In [2]: import sympy.physics.vector as vector

In [4]: N = vector.ReferenceFrame('N')

In [9]: vector.dot
Out[9]: <function sympy.physics.vector.functions.dot(vec1, vec2)>

In [10]: vector.dot(N.x,N.y)
Out[10]: 0
 
In [11]: vector.dot(N.x,N.x)
Out[11]: 1
 

In [12]: v1 = sqrt(3)*N.x + N.y 
    ...: v2 = sqrt(3)*N.x - N.y

In [13]: v1
Out[13]:
```

[image: ￼]

```
In [15]: type(v1)
Out[15]: sympy.physics.vector.vector.Vector

In [16]: vector.dot(v1,v2)
Out[16]: 2
```

You wondered about the `sqrt`:

```
In [17]: sqrt
Out[17]: <function sympy.functions.elementary.miscellaneous.sqrt(arg, evaluate=None)>
```

With a `z` symbol:

```
In [30]: vector.dot(z*N.x+N.y, z*N.x-N.y)
Out[30]:
```

[image: ￼]

Comment: Great, thanks. I actually found out that I defined a1 again in the code as a symbol. I removed the later re-definition of a1, which resolved the issue !